# NHK Slightly Harder News

Tags: discussion

I think I've finally reached the stage where NHK Easy News is easy (mostly). Filled with confidence in my now truly awesome Japanese skills I thought it was time to read the adult news. Big mistake. It's almost like a different language.

Aside from the massive lack of vocabulary my main problem is the grammar. When you miss out a few particles you get colloquial Japanese, but when you miss them **all** out, you get serious news stories.

What do kids in Japan do? Do they really jump straight from Easy News to the main site? Is there somewhere I can find something more intermediate? Any advice on how to make that jump would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally... I don't think kids want to read news in the main site... (the topic might be too heavy for them anyways). Take note that [understanding news is one of the hardest skill](https://www.jlpt.jp/e/about/pdf/cdslist_e_all.pdf). And personally, also as a self-learner, I'd go into hobby magazine/article/blog next... or teens/young adult novel... or anything else you feel interested in with your newly acquired Japanese skills :)

Comment: You guys are lucky there is such a thing as NHK Easy News now. (NHK Web Easy? Wow 振り仮名?!) There was nothing like that when I was struggling to learn Japanese in the mid-90s. Anyway, aside from doing it the hard way, e.g. actually trying to read, checking all unknown kanji, etc. I learned to read news mostly **by watching news** on tv. I made it a habit to place my 和英辞典 close to the tv, so everytime I hear something that I did not understand I could grab it quickly and find the meaning. Give it a try. I'm sure you could find Japanese news on the internet now, if you live outside Japan.

Comment: (continued) Listening to the news also helps your (of course) listening skills.

Comment: 昔から「子供新聞」とか「中高生新聞」みたいなのってありますね・・・紙で。ネットで無料で読めるかどうかわかんないですけど・・・たぶんこんな感じ → [朝日中高生新聞](https://digital.asagaku.com/chugaku/)、[読売中高生新聞](https://www.434381.jp/teen/)、[毎日小学生新聞](https://mainichi.jp/maisho/)、[朝日小学生新聞](https://www.asagaku.com/shimen.html)

Comment: When I lived in Japanese in the early 90's, the family I initially lived with would pull out news articles for me to read.  They were really challenging.  But the family was treating me like their own kids: constantly drilling down on kanji, how to read and recognize them and how to parse things like news paper articles and editorial pieces.  The news is still a struggle for me.  I understand the big picture, but the smaller details escape me.  If you can find the local news stories, those are often a lot less challenging.  Also, it helps to read the same stories first from the English press.